# Django3.0 add request.user to form request

Tags: python-3.x, forms, model, django-3.0

Let's say we have this model:

```py
class Creation(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=DEFAULT_LENGTH)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=DEFAULT_LENGTH)    
    date = models.DateTimeField('date published', default=datetime.date.today)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And let's use this view:

```py
def submit(request):
    FormSet = modelformset_factory(Creation, fields=('title', 'url'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = FormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
           obj = formset.save(commit=False)
            obj.author = request.user
            obj.save()
    else:
        formset = FormSet
    return render(request, 'app/submit.html', {'formset': formset})
```

I *saved* `formset` to `obj` and added `request.user` and committed it to the database.
This doesn't work, because now django throws an error which says

> 'list' object has no attribute 'author'

which makes perfectly sense, because there is no `author` in the fields-list above.
**But** if I add 'author' to `fields`, another selectbox would be displayed while rendering the template via `{{formset}}`.
Maybe I could code my own template-code instead of using `{{formset}}` and omit the author, but I feel that there must be a more elegant way with Django3.0. Is there any?

All I want to do is to get the foreignkey `author` (see model above) filled with the logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that something is wrong with `modelformset_factory(..)`.

If you use a proper `CreationForm` in `models.py`:

```py
class CreationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Creation
        fields = ['title', 'url']
```

and use it in your `views.py`:

```py
formset = CreationForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if formset.is_valid():
            f = formset.save(commit=False)
            f.author = request.user
            f.save()
```

it works.